# On a Windows Server, how do you prevent FTP from requiring the machine name to be included in the username?

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, plesk

I have a Windows server, and I'm using Plesk to manage many of the IIS and FTP settings. The server's machine name is 9WTBVY, and any FTP accounts that are created on the system cannot login unless the username is in the format *9WTBVY\username*.

If the user is named ftpuser, I want to be able to log in with the username *ftpuser*, and not *9WTBVY\ftpuser*. How do I do this?